# Deploy on Tomcat from eclipse in ROOT folder

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

Hi' I'd like to make my application deploy in ROOT folder (I hope to fix my problem about twice deploy).
I'm using maven and Tomcat v8 but even if I change pom.xml like below the result doesn't change.
I have tried to manually ad ROOT.war but when I start Tomcat from Eclipse it make deploy under application name folder. The path into the web modules is /ROOT
Do you know how can I deploy as ROOT.war? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>ROOT</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>ROOT</name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <name>The Apache Software License, Version 2.0</name>
            <url>http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt</url>
            <distribution>repo</distribution>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>4.2.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <spring.jpa.version>1.11.4.RELEASE</spring.jpa.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.42</mysql.connector.version>
        <logback.version>1.1.7</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.10.Final</hibernate.version>
        <dbcp.version>1.4</dbcp.version>
        <servletapi.version>2.5</servletapi.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>2.1.4.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleafspringsecurity4.version>2.1.2.RELEASE</thymeleafspringsecurity4.version>
        <thymeleaflayout.version>1.3.0</thymeleaflayout.version>
        <javax.version>3.1.0</javax.version>
        <nekohtml.version>1.9.22</nekohtml.version>
        <jacksondatatype.version>2.8.9</jacksondatatype.version>
        <jacksonjsr310.version>2.7.4</jacksonjsr310.version>
        <xmlapis.version>1.4.01</xmlapis.version>
        <swagger.version>2.7.0</swagger.version>
        <mqtt.version>1.1.1</mqtt.version>

    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.paho/org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
            <version>${mqtt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger for Web services documentation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.springfox/springfox-swagger-ui -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- database pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>${dbcp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate ORM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlapis.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
            <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
            <version>${nekohtml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaf.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleafspringsecurity4.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
            <version>${thymeleaflayout.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksonjsr310.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
            <version>${jacksondatatype.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring + aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ORM integration, e.g Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.jpa.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Spring Security -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- MySql Driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servletapi.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

If I export as ROOT.war and deploy from command line it works

Comment: what do you mean by ROOT folder? and where else do you want to deploy from?

Comment: in Tomcat there is the ROOT folder, i'd like to use this folder for my deploy instead of my_project_name folder

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [tomcat plugin](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/executable-war-jar.html) to do so with the following configuration:-

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path> <!-- root folder currently -->
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I think is it the same of setting from web modules. It create a new Context  tag into server.xml that duplicate the deploy

Answer (score 1):

This trick worked for me:

Before

[image: Before]

After
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue, and spend lots of time trying to find the solution. Eventually, I solved it so I'm posting the answer here so that my future self may find it again if required!

The m2e WTP integration uses a different property for the name it gives the target war file. See [M2E-WTP-FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E-WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_change_the_context_root_of_my_project.3F) for details.

Add the following code to pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <!-- Eclipse will use this value when auto-deploying into Tomcat -->
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    ...
    <build>
        <!-- Maven (and build servers) will use this value when building war -->
        <finalName>ROOT</finalName>
        ...
    </build>

</properties>
```